# Unintended consequences of .editorconfig indent_size

Tags: c#, .net, indentation, editorconfig

With an [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file, I can configure among other things how Visual Studio should indent code.

Now, the [.NET Compiler Platform's .editorconfig file](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/.editorconfig) as well as several other examples found on the web contain the following strange comment:

```
[*]
indent_style = space
# (Please don't specify an indent_size here; that has too many unintended consequences.)
```

What are these many unintended consequences when defining a default indent size for all file types? Should I avoid this in my own .editorconfig files as well, and only define indent sizes for specific filetypes?

It seems strange to define a default indent style (tabs/spaces) but not a default indent size.

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine, defining an indent size for *all files* can wreak havoc on you files when it is enforced.

YAML, Markdown and other file formats have significant white-space levels. An editor might have a limited level of support for these files (e.g. VSCode + plug-ins) and it might decide that since it now supports these files, the `.editorconfig` rules can be applied to it. If the file gets reformatted wrongly, the semantics change. Worst case, this happens automatically, and the result is also syntactically valid, but semantically different. That can cause nasty bugs.

A relatively benign, but annoying thing that might happen is that all your Markdown nested lists are suddenly flattened, if the formatter decides that they all should have the same indent.